# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT after updating to sonoma and xcode 15

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode15

I updated from xcode 14.x to 15.x and also updated from venture to sonoma operating system. Now my app crashes at runtime. I'm trying to run it on a tethered iPad that was previously working for testing the app this way. It crashes after the initial splash image for my app loads. The simulator appears to crash too when I try it on a simulator.

Here's what I see. Any ideas what could be wrong? I tried setting an exception breakpoint but it didn't break. I've tried clean build, quitting xcode, restarting, legacy system, etc.
I'm not sure if this was just a warning or if it's an error that caused the abrt: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods

Thank you in advance for any help on this.
[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: Hard to tell with the little information you provided. What dependencies does the project have?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean everything in package.json? What I suspect is possibly a 3rd party library we are using for printing. Or possibly one we are using for scanning barcodes.

Comment: What i have seen so far, this type of error usually arises from dependencys that are not up to date. You didn´t provide any information of what packages or frameworks you use. Deriving from your comment I am assuming there are dependencies or frameworks you use in your application. Please try to update these to the latest version and test again. If this does´nt work you are probably better of asking for help on the support site for the dependencies. Or at least tag the question appropriatly.

Comment: thanks, it appears to be an issue of having to update reactnative.